# how to add entry in crontab to run a script with particular user?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I am adding a entry in crontab to run a script:
`crontab -e` [enter]
`19 08 01 09 2 source ~/.bash_profile ; /t3/musr/Mycomp/Scripts/db_to_file.ksh > /t3/musr/Mycomp/Logs/ims_ucm_log.log`

Currently this is failing as it is being run by some other user. [who is the default user for crontab jobs ?]

How do I run this as `user13` in using crontab ?
I am running it now by logging in as user `deep_38` and i am doing `sudo user13` and running the script. It runs successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is not default crontab user, each user has its own crontab config.

In your case you need to run `crontab -e` as `user13`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , kindly trek me How to run that? And what if I want to mention different uses to different entries in single crontab?

Comment: `sudo user13` then `crontab -e` (as `user13`). Different `uses` or `users`? You can't have cron jobs for different users in the same crontab, each needs their own crontab. Take a look at `man crontab`.

Comment: @DanCornilescu "You can't have cron jobs for different users in the same crontab" - yes, you can, but not in a user-specific crontab that is the result of using `crontab -e` - it would have to be in /etc/crontab or one of the /etc/cron.* directory-style crontabs. Of course modifying one of those typically requires root privilege, though...

Comment: @twalberg: True that. But personally I would use that only for admin purposes and only with scripts I write/trust, not as a convenience for running users' scripts :)

Comment: I added it in `crontab` as `user13`, this `user13` is in tty group so has write permission to `/dev/stderr`. when script is run manually as  `user13` , it does not throw any error. where as when it is added to crontab and is run as user13 it errors out saying `OS Error: Permission Denied` when script tries to write to `/dev/stderr`